# Configure sonarcloud.io with Github Pull Request Decorations

Tags: github, sonarqube

I would like to setup Sonarcloud to decorate pull requests on github following this documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/github-application/

But I can't find the "Administration > Pull Requests > GitHub > GitHub App private key." option.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 3):

Just followed this documentation is the good path to use sonarcloud.io with github.com https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/integrations/github/

Configure sonar to add your deposit and Install sonar GitHub app our your repository.

Then add few options to your sonar build. Sample from doc:

```
sonar.pullrequest.base=master
sonar.pullrequest.branch=feature/my-new-feature
sonar.pullrequest.key=5
sonar.pullrequest.provider=GitHub
sonar.pullrequest.github.repository=my-company/my-repo
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Their saas and on premise doc are separate. Looking on Google to achieve pull request decoration, I found the on premise page and tried to follow it. But it was impossible because I am using saas version of their software, so following the bad doc was not the best idea. The option I was looking for doesn't exist in the saas version.